# Autocompleter In JSP Not Working With NTLM Code

Tags: java, jsp, autocomplete, ntlm

I am having a strange issue with autocompleter in JSP when application is authenticated through NTLM. After NTLM authentication code is passed and re-directed to JSP page, my autocompleter doesn't work at all. I am using the following for autocompleter `Ajax.Autocompleter("emp","autocomp","getajaxdata.jsp");`
[For reference](http://todotomorrow.blogspot.com/2005/06/ajax-autocompletion.html)

If I remove the NTLM authentication code from my application, then autocompleter would work.
How can I resolve this issue? Strangely this issue only occurs in IE, in firefox it works fine.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Regards

Code I used for NTLM authentication in servlet

```
 public void service(HttpServletRequest request, 
                        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        /**
        * Coding to find out the current logged in user name
        **/
        String username="";
        String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (auth == null)
        {
        response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
        response.flushBuffer();
        return;
        }
        if (auth.startsWith("NTLM "))
        {
        byte[] msg = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(auth.substring(5));
        int off = 0, length, offset;
        if (msg[8] == 1)
        {
        byte z = 0;
        byte[] msg1 = {(byte)'N', (byte)'T', (byte)'L', (byte)'M', (byte)'S', (byte)'S', (byte)'P',
        z,(byte)2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z,(byte)40, z, z, z,
        (byte)1, (byte)130, z, z,z, (byte)2, (byte)2,
        (byte)2, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z, z};
        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM " +
        new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(msg1).trim());
        response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return;
        }
        else if (msg[8] == 3)
        {
        off = 30;

        length = msg[off+9]*256 + msg[off+8];
        offset = msg[off+11]*256 + msg[off+10];
        username = new String(msg, offset, length);
        }
        }
        /**
         * Coding for removing extra white spaces from the user name
         */
        String windname="";
        String  windname1=username.replaceAll(" ",null  );
        int l=username.length();           
        int i=0;
        while (i<l)
        {
          if (username.charAt(i)==0)
          {
          }
          else
          {
              char temp=username.charAt(i);
              windname=windname+temp;
          }
          i++;
        }
```

Comment: In other words, MSIE doesn't send the correct `WWW-Authenticate` request header along? What framework are you using to send Ajax requests?

Comment: @BalusC I didn't quite understand your comment, but am sure WWW_Authenticate request is sent correctly and hence authentication works fine. Regarding framework to send Ajax request`Ajax.Autocompleter("emp","autocomp","getajaxdata.jsp");`.  **the implementation is mainly thru javascript - only the backend that returns results would be language/platform specific** For reference please see here as I followed [this]http://todotomorrow.blogspot.com/2005/06/ajax-autocompletion.html article.

Comment: If I remove the following line from NTLM authentication code, then issue doesn't occur `response.sendError(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);` Why this line is causing the problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Any one could provide some insight?

Comment: Still awaiting response, as I am desperately looking for a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having similar problems and I found this:

[posted with empty data (sporadical)](http://www.websina.com/bugzero/kb/browser-ie.html)

If you do searching around... NTLM does some funny things:

[Some more info on NTLM](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html#preemptive_auth)